# Always return element value from current node with XPath

Tags: xml, xpath, infopath

**Edit:** This question should read "How do I point to an element in the context node?" Answer is quite simple in this situation. From Larsh's response:
`"my:Line_Item_Mod_0 = 'true'"`

Also, forgive me if this was a highly obvious question; I didn't know the terminology for "Context Node" which is probably why google and the StackOverflow search weren't helping much.

Read the remainder of the question for context.

I need an XPath expression that returns the current `Line_Item_Mod_0` value within each node in order to conditionally format an MS InfoPath form. I'm quite green to XPath and I don't know what the appropriate term for this behavior (exhibited by an expression) is. Here is my XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><?mso-infoPathSolution solutionVersion="1.0.0.504" productVersion="14.0.0" PIVersion="1.0.0.0" href="file:///C:\Documents%20and%20Settings\Chris\Local%20Settings\Application%20Data\Microsoft\InfoPath\Designer3\c37482678ae440c9\manifest.xsf" ?><?mso-application progid="InfoPath.Document" versionProgid="InfoPath.Document.2"?><?mso-infoPath-file-attachment-present?>
<my:myFields xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xhtml="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:dfs="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/infopath/2003/dataFormSolution" xmlns:pc="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/infopath/2007/PartnerControls" xmlns:my="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/infopath/2003/myXSD/2011-05-05T19:56:08" xmlns:xd="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/infopath/2003" xml:lang="en-us">
<my:MasterSection>
    <my:Project_Information>
        <my:Line_Items>
            <my:Counter>1</my:Counter>
            <my:Authorized_Number>4</my:Authorized_Number>
            <my:XPathLINCounter>Line Item 1</my:XPathLINCounter>
            <my:Line_Item_Mod_0>false</my:Line_Item_Mod_0>
        </my:Line_Items>
        <my:Line_Items>
            <my:Counter>2</my:Counter>
            <my:Authorized_Number>7</my:Authorized_Number>
            <my:XPathLINCounter>Line Item 2</my:XPathLINCounter>
            <my:Line_Item_Mod_0>true</my:Line_Item_Mod_0>
        </my:Line_Items>
        <my:Line_Items>
            <my:Counter>3</my:Counter>
            <my:Authorized_Number>2</my:Authorized_Number>
            <my:XPathLINCounter>Line Item 3</my:XPathLINCounter>
            <my:Line_Item_Mod_0>false</my:Line_Item_Mod_0>
        </my:Line_Items>
    </my:Project_Information>
</my:MasterSection>
</my:myFields>
```

I am trying to evaluate whether the "mod" value for the current node is 1 or 0. I already have an expression that does this, but for some reason InfoPath conditional formatting doesn't like it. You can see the results of this mod expression in the `Line_Item_Mod_0` element.

All I need to do is target the `Line_Item_Mod_0` element within each `Line_Items` node. I can't seem to make an expression that returns the value of the `Line_Item_Mod_0` for its parent node (or perhaps "current" is the correct term).

I.E. `Line_Items` node 1 would have an expression within it that ALWAYS returns the `false` value of `Line_Item_Mod_0`.

I realize this should be simple, but I can't seem to get my expression to stick within its current node.

The expression `(count(preceding-sibling::my:*) + 1) mod 2 > 0` generates the `Line_Item_Mod_0` node but doesn't play nice with conditional formatting if I apply it as a rule. I can't tell why.

I want to try to bypass it and evaluate the "true" or "false" value directly.

Comment: "I already have an expression that does this, but for some reason InfoPath conditional formatting doesn't like it. You can see the results of this mod expression in the Line_Item_Mod_0 element." Where are we supposed to see this? This sentence makes it sound as though parts of your XML sample given above are the *output* of your XPath expressions, but the rest of the question suggests that the given XML is *input* to the XPath you're trying to figure out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever the current node (context node) is a `<my:Line_Items>` element, the following XPath expression will return the value of its `<my:Line_Item_Mod_0>` child element:

```
"my:Line_Item_Mod_0"
```

This XPath expression will actually select an element node; if that element node is evaluated in a string context, its value will be the string content of its child text node, `false` or `true`. If you need to convert that to a boolean, use

```
"my:Line_Item_Mod_0 = 'true'"
```

Note however, that this XPath expression uses a **namespace prefix**. In order for that usage to be valid, you have to declare that namespace prefix in the context of the XPath processor. You haven't shown any of the context of how you are invoking XPath, but if you do show us that, we should be able to help verify that that part is done correctly.

Also you mention "conditional formatting" a couple of times, but with insufficient detail to do anything with. I'm treating it as unimportant for now, but if it's important, please edit your answer to post examples so we can help you with it.

Comment: Thank you for your response! It was exactly what I needed. In fact, it was a lot simpler than I thought it would be... MS InfoPath is processing my XPath; I don't know exactly how it handles the expressions. InfoPath is applying conditional formatting (alternating shades on form fields) to make the form more readable. I figured I would have to use an axis of some kind to point to the context node (I didn't even know that it was called the context node!). Turns out that's not the case! I greatly appreciate your help.

Comment: Also, forgive me if this was a highly obvious question; I didn't know the terminology for "Context Node" which is probably why google and the StackOverflow search weren't helping much.

Comment: @Chris: No problem - I've been in the same boat many times, searching for how to do something and not knowing what terms to use. This is where reading a tutorial or two can be time well spent. Glad to be of help.

Comment: I've been through the W3Schools tutorial several times, though I might have a deeper understanding at this point if I reviewed it again. Do you have any particulary good recommendations for tutorials? I have the XSLT & XPath 2.0 textbook, but man talk about a read. I'm up for anything useful though! And I'll get through that book in time...

Comment: @Chris: Good question. I find that W3Schools is rather poor on terminology and fundamental concepts. What you learn there sometimes turns out to be incorrect. Here's a link to a couple of authoritative tutorials: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2306680/423105